# Vagrant Install chef-client on top of base image

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm trying to use Chef to install graphite server and I encountered errors saying that either chef-solo or chef-client was not found on the VM. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.amd64 LTS, this is server version so it will not have chef-client installed. I know that 13 version will auto have chef-client installed but I can not use 13 version.

I googled and saw some people suggest to ssh to the box and apt-get install chef-client.

My question is: is there anyway that I can preinstall chef-client before chef kicked in? Basically I would like my chef program download the raw image and do everything without additional manual steps from users. Is it possible?

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu-12.04-amd64"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
    config.vm.hostname = "graphite"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 9090

    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
      chef.roles_path = "roles"
      chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
      chef.add_role "Graphite-Server"
      chef.add_role "StatsD-Server"
    end
end
```

Error Log:

```
[default] Running provisioner: chef_solo...
The chef binary (either `chef-solo` or `chef-client`) was not found on
the VM and is required for chef provisioning. Please verify that chef
is installed and that the binary is available on the PATH.
```

Thanks

Comment: I found some solutions here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/19

Comment: It depends on your base box, if chef is preinstalled. I'm very sure that also Ubuntu 13.* has chef *preeinstalled*, only available through `apt`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "also Ubuntu 13.* has chef **not** *preeinstalled*"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found 2 solutions and both work as expected:

**1) Method 1:**
In your Vagrantfile, add

`config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest`

This will make sure either **chef-solo** or **chef-client** is installed on the VM and is required for chef provisioning. In order to use omnibus plugin, make sure you install the plugin first: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus`

**2) Method 2:** Use **`config.vm.provision`** shell inline as mentioned here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/19#issuecomment-15487131. In your Vagrantfile, add:

`config.vm.provision "shell", path: "utils/tools/install_chef.bash"`

The script **utils/tools/install_chef.bash** that I wrote looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function error
{
    echo -e "\033[1;31m${1}\033[0m" 1>&2
}

function checkRequireRootUser
{
    if [[ "$(whoami)" != 'root' ]]
    then
        error "ERROR: please run this program as 'root'"
        exit 1
    fi
}

function installChef()
{
    if [[ "$(which chef-client)" = '' ]]
    then
        local chefProfilePath='/etc/profile.d/chef.sh'

        curl -s -L 'https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh' | bash && \
        echo 'export PATH="/opt/chef/embedded/bin:$PATH"' > "${chefProfilePath}" && \
        source "${chefProfilePath}"
    fi
}

function main()
{
    checkRequireRootUser
    installChef
}

main
```

**UPDATE:**

if you get following error: `Unknown configuration section 'omnibus'`. It means you are missing omnibus plugin. To install it, type: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus`

Comment: Sure, that's okay, too. I had something similar before, too. In case you have a slow internet connection, you could put the `.deb` file somewhere, where it is available via synced folders (either below the directory, where your `Vagrantfile` is or using an additional share). Then you can just do `dpkg -i chef*.deb` to install chef without the need to download over and over again.

Comment: huh... excellent idea. This could be a third method how to solve the issue. I will try it out! Thanks @StephenKing

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend the [vagrant-omnibus](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus) plugin that basically executes the `install.sh` script for you, if chef is not installed.

Comment: Or just use Test Kitchen :)