# Vagrant: Unknown configuration section 'omnibus' but vagrant-omnibus plugin is installed

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I've followed the instructions at:  http://berkshelf.com/ after installing the latest ChefDK (from here: http://downloads.getchef.com/chef-dk/mac/#/). When I do "vagrant up", I get the error:

```
Vagrant:
* Unknown configuration section 'omnibus'.
```

Various posts (e.g. [Vagrant Install chef-client on top of base image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274437/vagrant-install-chef-client-on-top-of-base-image)) have suggested this means that the vagrant-omnibus plugin is not installed. In my case, I have installed it.  "vagrant plugin list" displays:

```
vagrant-berkshelf (2.0.1)
  - Version Constraint: 2.0.1
vagrant-login (1.0.1, system)
vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
vagrant-share (1.1.1, system)
```

Any suggestions as to how I can get this example cookbook to run on a new VM instance launched with "vagrant up"?

Answer (score 9):

It turns out the issue for me was that while `~/.vagrant.d/plugins.json` included the vagrant-omnibus plugin, the `~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems` and `~/.vagrant.d/gems/specifications` directories did not contain the appropriate GEM or gemspec files. Not sure how this happened, but I suspect it was due to accidentally typing `^C` in the middle of execution of the vagrant plugin install command and then reexecuting that command.

It would appear `vagrant plugin install` does not do appropriate `^C` handling and that it writes the contents of `plugins.json` before it has stored the gem and gemspec.

Subsequent `vagrant plugin install` commands don't fix the problem. Manually editing `plugins.json` to remove the plugin and then reexecuting the `vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus` command fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, I tried steps that you described, but they didn't work. I still get error         * Unknown configuration section 'omnibus'. Can you please point what to do  in order to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I personally went inside the vagrant file using VI editor
and commented out the line that has omni bus script
and then run "
vagrant status" and then "vagrant up"

1.vi Vagrant
2.?omnibus
3."insert" I omnibus
4.insert # to comment out the line
5. wq! to come out of vi editor

** this issue can also be related with the type of OS one is using ,i am using a mac