# Unknown configuration section 'omnibus'

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I faced the same issue as described here: [Vagrant: Unknown configuration section 'omnibus' but vagrant-omnibus plugin is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632708/vagrant-unknown-configuration-section-omnibus-but-vagrant-omnibus-plugin-is-i)

I done all steps described in answer, but I still get the same error. 
What should be done to solve this issue?

I try to do  `vagrant up` but I get error `Unknown configuration section 'omnibus'.`

Plugin is described in `plugins.json` file, directories
`.vagrant.d\gems\2.2.5\gems\vagrant-omnibus-1.5.0` and `.vagrant.d\gems\2.2.5\specifications` contain gemspec files.

My OS is Windows 7(I don't know but maybe it is cause of problem)

Answer (score 0):

`vagrant-omnibus` is completely unnecessary these days. Vagrant itself supports everything you need and it is enabled by default when using a Chef provisioner: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_common.html